# Prove that $ \lfloor \frac{ \lfloor x \rfloor+m}{n} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{x+m}{n}\rfloor $

Tags: calculus, analysis

Prove that $ \lfloor \frac{ \lfloor x \rfloor+m}{n} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{x+m}{n}\rfloor  $,

where  $ x \in \mathbb{R}, m \in  \mathbb{Z}, n \in  \mathbb{Z} $. I even don't know how to start to prove it, I would appreciate any kind of help.

I made the following proof, does it maybe help to find the proof to the original question?

$ \lfloor x+n \rfloor \le  x+n < \lfloor x+n \rfloor +1 \implies $

$\lfloor x+n \rfloor -n \le x < \lfloor x+n \rfloor -n +1 \implies$

$\lfloor x\rfloor = \lfloor x+n \rfloor -n \implies$

$\lfloor x+n \rfloor = \lfloor x\rfloor +n $

Comment: Please update your post to include your thoughts, you must have some.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $m$ an integer, we have $$
\lfloor x \rfloor + m = 
\lfloor x+m \rfloor.
$$

Comment: Refrain from answering low quality questions: see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: From the referenced item: "When engaging with users (old or new) who have posted (or answered) a low-quality question, remember to remain polite and courteous. Please do not issue unpleasant orders [...]"

Answer (score 0):

Hint:On the right hand side, write $x=\lfloor{x}\rfloor+\{x\}$. Then consider the fact that $\frac {\{x\}}{n}<1$

Comment: Refrain from answering low quality questions: see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).